# Looking for a better algorithn of findins substrings in strings using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

**UPDATE**

I'll add some info about the problem to give you a better idea about why is everything done the way it is.

The main point of the whole script is to find all errors in a special file that keeps original and translated strings.

The script requires the "special" bilingual file(an xml in real life) and a "special" vocabulary file which keeps words and their tranlations(xls, xlsx constructed by hand. PO would probably be better.)

As a result it find all errors in translation, using the provided vocabulary.

Obviously if the vocab is bad the result sucks.

At some point of time the whole thing used 'std' or mostly 'std' and 'boost regular expressions'.

At some other point of time came the need for utf-8 support, including the regular expressions. We had no time to write complex stuff, so it was decided to go the QT way.

We were aware that it is possible to iterate over bytes. But we needed actual letters and sequences of letters also we needed to cut the word ending which is done though regular expressions, and no other regex supports utf-8 relatively good.

It was decided that Qt fitted the role far better  than anything we would write ourselves in very limited time, as Qt has utf-8 support, and as of v5 keeps all internal stings as utf-8 encoded(as far as I am aware).

It was pointed out that complexity of proposed solution looks like O(m * n).
In reality it's probably even worse - closer to O(m * n * log(l)) or even O(m * n * l) strait. Here m is number of strings, n - number of vocabulary records, l - number of synonyms each word has(l is always at least equals 1).

Since we need to check all strings, and for each string run the whole vocabulary to find all errors, I currently see no way how can we make it any faster, because there is no real way faster.

---

As the question implies I am looking for a better solution to an existing coding problem.
I am gonna try to explain what exactly the problem is as best as I can.

Imagine you have a piece of code written on C++ that takes a string, a translation of the string,
gets rid of pesky word endings.
After that it takes **another** file which is a vocabulary and actually runs the whole vocab to find out whether the translation of the string has any errors.

Obviously this thing is highly dependent on the actual vocabulary, but that is not really a problem.

I actually have a described piece of code, although I need to mention the whole thing runs through CGI(don't ask, but at some point it was decided that C++ will run it faster). I can have the full code uploaded to git repo, it's rather big, but I will share the essential parts here.

The current problem I am facing is two fold: either the code does not find all it is supposed to, or it works too slow(probably gets stuck somewhere, but I have not yet pin pointed where)

The main idea behind the code was:

```
// All definitions for essential structures so you have a better idea what he hell is goind on
struct Word {
  QString full = "";
  QString stemmed = "";
};

struct VocRecord {
  QVector<Word> orig;
  QVector<Word> trans;

  QString error = "";

  void clearRecord() {
    this->orig.clear();
    this->trans.clear();
    this->error = "";
  }
};

typedef QVector<VocRecord> Vocabluary;

......

Vocabluary voc = .....; // Obviosly here we get the vocabulary, now how we get it is rather complicated, you can just assume it looks like defined vector of records.

QString origStemmed, transStemmed, orig, trans;

// orig - original string
// trans - it's translation
// origStemmed - original string with removed word endings (we call it stemming hence stemmed)
// transStemmed - transtalion with removed word endings.
```

At first the algo was something along the lines of:

```
origStemmed = QString(" ") + origStemmed + QString(" ");           // Add whitespaces in the begin and end of string for searching
transStemmed = QString(" ") + transStemmed + QString(" ");

for(int i = 0; i < voc.length(); i++) {
  VocRecord record = voc[i];

  for(int j = 0; j < record.orig.length(); j++) {
    Word origWord =  record.orig[j];

    si = origStemmed.indexOf(QString(" ") + origWord.stemmed + QString(" "));

    if(si > -1) {

      int ind = origWord.stemmed.indexOf(" ");
      int idx = 0;

      if(ind != -1) {
        // Found a space in record, means record contains at least two words. 
        // Here we care where the firs word ends, an it's part of the global problem
        idx = origMod.indexOf(origWord.full.mid(0, ind));
      } else {
        // We did not find a space, do one word only, take the whole thing.
        idx = origMod.indexOf(origWord.full);
      }
      // Now comes the tricky part, we try to figure out if that original text, in which we found our voc record, had any punctuation after the word. 
      // Now this actually matters only for records that have more then one word in reality, but as you'll see we check all of them and that is not correct - still figuring how to get around it.

      QChar symb; - // We'll keep our last symbol of first word here
      // originMod - modified original: everything is lowercase, punctuation is kept.
      // The main reason we have this at all is because when stemming we have to  get rid of all punctuation so we keep the "lowercased" string separate.
      // I am 100% sure we don't need it at all since Qt supporrts case insensitive search, but I would like to hear your opinion on it.

      if(origMod.indexOf(" ", idx) > 0) {
        symb = origMod[origMod.indexOf(" ", idx)-1];
      } else {
        symb = origMod[origMod.length()-1];
      }

      // When we have the last symbol we skip the the found word
      if(ind != -1 && (symb == QChar(',') || symb == QChar(';') || symb == QChar('!') || symb == QChar(':') || symb == QChar('?') || symb == QChar('.'))) {
        continue;
      }
      // The important part ends here
      ............
```

As you will notice we search for stemmed word in the original string.
by all accounts it should work, but the main problem of proposed search that it can have several matches including false ones, and we only care about first found one. The most obvious solution is probably go through all matches, but I am unsure that is a good idea, it requires another loop and the algo is quite slow already.

The  next solution I came up with to solving the problem was using regular expressions, but I must have messed up, because the algo started to be "really slow".

The main idea of the second solution:

```
// We DO not add spaces! spaces suck big time.
for(int i = 0; i < voc.length(); i++) {
  VocRecord record = voc[i];

  for(int j = 0; j < record.orig.length(); j++) {
    Word origWord =  record.orig[j];

    // In stead of using spaces, we search for a regular expression made from vocab record.
    // The simple contains actually runs into the same set of problems namely more then one match or in some cases false matches(when the searched part matches something it should not).
    // Now this is terribly slow as you can imagine because we create regular expressions on the fly and not pre-make them. But I still have not thought of a way around it.

    if(origStemmed.contains(origWord.stemmed + "\\b",
      QRegularExpression::UseUnicodePropertiesOption | QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption))) {

      // Here we do something ungodly. We take our stemmed voc record, split it by space, then go through all parts making striing that will become our regular expression later

      QString temp;
      parts.clear();
      parts = origWord.stemmed.split(" ");
      
      for(int k = 0; k < parts.count(); k++) {
        temp += "\\b" + parts[k] + "[a-z]*?\\b";
      }
      
      // After we added everything we need? we join the whole thing back by spaces.
      temp = parts.join(" ");
  
      // And here is the Ungodly chech - we actually search for the made regular expression in the original sting, and because we made sure to exclude any punctuation from expression in theory this should work.
      if(!origMod.contains(QRegularExpression(temp, QRegularExpression::UseUnicodePropertiesOption | QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption))) {
        continue;
      }
      // Well it does not work, or rather it works so slow - it's impossible to get any result, and even if we do, we still don't find everything we should - I blame the shitty regex here.
      // And the important part ends.
```

As I pointed the second solution sucks big time. Currently I am aiming for some intermediate solution and would gladly accept any tips or suggestions you can make on where to look or what to look for.

If any of you will want to see the full code for this thing - just add a comment, I'll github all the important files in a separate repo.

Comment: I didn’t read all of your attempts but I would suggest that the solution you develop will be most reusable if the core is implemented in terms of iterators and std algorithms rather than an indexing `for` loop and the quirky Qt member functions like `indexOf`.

Comment: @Ben unfortunately  that is  not really an option. At some point of time it did use std iterators, but than came need for UTF-8 support. Because time was very limited it was decided to use Qt as a basis for utf-8 support(native as of Qt 5 as far as I am aware). Std iterators had to go unfortunately.

Comment: Also, you say it’s slow. What big-O do you think it has? It looks like it’s O(M*N) when hopefully it can be O(M log(N))…

Comment: You can still iterate over the bytes, though…

Comment: I posted a small update at the very top of the question explaining a bit why everything is done the way it is.

Comment: If anyone has any idea on which stack the problem is easier to solve and does not run into pesky utf-8 support problems, the ideas about stack change are welcome